# Iterating over a list of objects, checking if their properties are defined

Tags: c#, listiterator

I have a list of objects. Is there a way to iterate over the list and check whether any of their properties is not defined?

I have tried something like

```
list.FindAll(p => p.property == null);
```

but as a desired property is double I am getting a warning, that the expression will always evaluate to false.

Comment: A `double` can never be null, so what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Can you use `p => p.Property == default(double)`?

Comment: You need to create a comparer with a define "null" equivalent value for non nullable types. Example you can decide that `double` are null when they are equal to `double.MinValue`. Because even using `default(type)` it may return a valid value for you.

Comment: What "*property is not defined*" means in your context? If you need an "any" expression you can use the `.Any(/* expression */)` extension method on `IEnumerable`

Comment: Maybe you want to use `double?`

Comment: @TimSchmelter - maybe reword your question for someone unfamiliar with the syntax of a nullable double this now looks like the question mark of your question - even knowing the syntax I fell for it :)

Comment: @RandRandom:; you're right, even though questions normally don't begin with _Maybe_ ;-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter - TIL english :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Maybe your comment was an exception?  (Sorry, I couldn't help myself, I'll see my way out now.)

Answer (score 1):

Because `double` can't be null, you can use `double?`.

Then, continue your logic, it's `null` means it's not defined

Answer (score 1):

If the property can't be 0. Basing this response on Yojin response, the easiest way would be to check for 0 instead of `null`.

```
list.FindAll(p => p.property == 0);
```

Of course if at any point the property could be equal to 0 then this should be avoided.
There is nullable type of course. The declaration of your property would be something like this :

```
public double? MyProperty { get; set; }
```

If nothing is attributed to the property it is `null` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Value types can never be null so in the instance of saying

```
double x;
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
```

You're going to see the '0' get written out.

If you're interested you should check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types